# Xamarin.iOS Project Missing References Error after Upgrade to 4.5.0.396

Tags: xamarin.forms, reference, xamarin.ios

I have upgraded my Xamarin.Forms Project to 4.4 to 4.5.0.396 and I am gettng iOS project missing references error for all references. It seems they are still there and there is no nuget package missing in folder. As a consequence I get error missing reference in appdelegate and assembly files. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acqvf.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlwQQ.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2veC.png)

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! You can have a try with re-install Nuget Package to check whehter it works .

Comment: Same problem here - I don't believe this is the usual "clean house and rebuild" scenario, something is actually wrong with .396 so I'm not sure why it got pushed to nuget stable.  Even the official release notes haven't been updated beyond .356:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that the reason is the upgrade of Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package.
Usually, this happens when you delete the `bin` and `obj` directory.
When, I delete the `bin` and `obj` directories, usually, I wait a bit until the directories are recreated by Visual Studio.
There were a couple of times that I needed to close the solution and Visual Studio and open it again.